# How to map Cura printspace to Prusa I3 printspace

Tags: prusa-i3, ultimaker-cura, axis

I seem to be observing a couple problems w/ Cura2.3 OSX . It seems to be placing the sliced data (gcode) over to negative X by a cm or so.  Further, the X- and Y-axes displayed in Cura definitely map to Y and X when the printer starts up. I've verified that I have the printer's X and Y end stops and motors connected to the correct outputs. Now, I can just rotate my parts before slicing, but I'd rather have things be "correct" to begin with. 
I've read the relevant info at [question 1323](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/how-to-line-up-x-y-print-area-between-hardware-and-software), but I'd rather if possible adjust the Printer Settings for my defined printer in the Cura Preferences sub-menu. I couldn't find any description of what the "printer head" X and Y offset values mean there, nor what the "Z-gantry" value does either.
I'm running from the SD card; no USB connection.

Comment: Carl, not sure if it would help, but [this ultimaker thread](https://ultimaker.com/en/community/21180-cura-211-print-bed-size-offset) seems to have lots of relevant discussion.  Maybe some tidbit there will help.

Comment: @ChrisThompson Thanks, I suspected commanding an offset might be what's needed.  I'll hit the Home command on my LCD interface and see where the extruder nozzle sits.

Comment: When you figure it out, you should answer your own question...I think it would add value.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in my particular case, it helps to have the X and Y control (motor and endstop switch) plugged in to the correct ports :-( .  That took care of the X vs. Y orientation problem.

If you command "Home All" either via the LCD panel or over USB, the nozzle should sit in the front left corner of the bed as you face the machine ("stage right" for you thespians). 
The link Chris T provided, [ultimaker](https://ultimaker.com/en/community/21180-cura-211-print-bed-size-offset), provides helpful background information as well.

Next, if there are small offsets, find control can be set with a script similar to the following (leave out the auto-levelling command if you don't have that),
from [printerbot talk forum](http://www.printrbottalk.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=9883) .

```
M104 S{print_temperature}
G21 ;metric values
G90 ;absolute positioning
M82 ;set extruder to absolute mode
M107 ;start with the fan off
G28 X0 Y0 ;move X/Y to min endstops
G28 Z0 ;move Z to min endstops
M109 S{print_temperature} ;wait on temperature line
G29 ; Auto bed levelling
;G28 X0 Y0 ;move X/Y to min endstops
G92 X132.4 Y20; Reset actual position after G29 bug
G92 E0 ;zero the extruded length
G1 F{travel_speed}
```

And finally, there's a calibration file at [thingiverse](http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:13053) which prints large squares so you can see the exact offset.  I hope to get that file modded with a couple markers (indents, e.g.) to verify orientation as well as location.